# Word or expression for guys who slept with the same woman(prostitute)?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, slang, translation

Embarrassingly, in Korean, there is a slang word for this kind of relationship between guys.

Might be translated as, "the husband of my wife's sister but only by the hole" ?

I don't know how can I call the husband of my wife's sister in English. Korean word is "Dong-suh 동서(同壻)". That is, Korean people don't say "Hank is the husband of Mr. White's wife's sister" but "Hank is the Mr. White's dong-suh".

With this kinship terminology, if some Korean guys found out that they have slept with the same woman (in many cases a prostitute or a professional), they might jokingly call each other "구멍(hole)동서(the husband of my wife's sister)". It has f-word level vulgarism.

Is there similar slang word/expression in English?

**UPDATED**

I forgot "brother-in-law". Original words is something like "brother-in-hole". In here, 'Hole' symbolizes the vagina. So I mentioned vulgarism.

Comment: The husband of my wife's sister is called a "brother-in-law" but this has absolutely no level of vulgarism associated with it. I know of no English equivalent for what you're asking.

Comment: "Brother Johns"?  (okay, no one uses this, but it actually kind of works, as a "John" is the guy who hires a prostitute)

Comment: Is there a registry somewhere that keeps track of who sleeps with whom and what their family relations are?

Comment: I hope that English has a [semantic gap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_gap#Semantic_gaps) here!

Comment: Dict.cc suggests *Eskimo brother* and *wiener cousin* as equivalents for *Lochschwager*, but I have never heard *wiener cousin* before.

Comment: If we're creating neologisms, I vote for "john brothers" instead of "brother johns" which works even better for the level of cleanliness expected of popular working girls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I can think of is *fellow johns of (woman's name)*.

A [john](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/john) is a well-recognized slang for the client of a prostitute:

> a man who pays money to a prostitute for sex (MW)

Comment: This shouldn't have been downvoted, but an explanation that a John is slang for a client of a prostitute might have been helpful.

Answer (score 5):

[Eskimo Brothers](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Eskimo%20Brother)

> When two males acknowledge having been intimate with the same female
>   and remain on good terms, the men are now bonded by having shared the
>   same igloo at one time or another.
>
> This can lead to perks by making the information known to other males
>   who you can network with. Male 1: "Yea man, I got us a hook up at the
>   show tonight, we don't have to pay cover"
>
> Male 2: "Sweet, how'd you score that?"
>
> Male 1: "Me and the door guy are **eskimo brothers**, remember that blonde
>   girl from last weekend?"
>
> *from Urban Dictionary*

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard this term before. Is it limited to a particular regionn? I'd honestly interpret it as some sort of euphemism for two guys having had sex together.

Comment: @guifa It originated as a vulgarization of a [misunderstanding of Eskimo customs](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2066/do-eskimo-men-lend-their-wives-to-strangers) in North America. I have heard it used in the U.S. for a number of years, but it may have been recently popularized by [an early episode](http://theleague.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bounce_Test) of the television sitcom *[The League](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1480684)*, first aired on the FX network in 2009.

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have noted, there are no commonly-used phrases for this even though some subcultures may have a term and most people would probably understand "fellow johns of" a woman. For what it's worth, in Chinese, there's a fairly common equivalent term that's also familial, but they go with the term *maternal uncles* instead.

Answer (score 0):

In California millennial generation we would almost always describe such a dynamic as him " having my sloppy seconds "  as in the first guy made the woman sloppy and the second guy consumed his leftovers.  That's what you would say about your friend sleeping with you ex, or
If you visited the same hooker, or if you were thd type to have sex with a party girl.  A guy getting sloppy seconds is derogatory to the female and is slightly condescending to the second guy but it's not always offensive between the males and can be used as a simplified way to show acceptance of their sleeping with her as well as them acknowledging that they recycled your skis so they don't have to be apologetic but accept that they opted to faux Pas. Sloppy seconds is the most accurate reference to what your trying to translate.  We don't have a shared title that is equal except " we both hit it" in which case whoever was last is automatically categorized as " got your  sloppy seconds" even if it's not stated.